# fill input fields with json data then sent to the printer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

i want to fill input fields with data from json and then sent it to the printer and then again to fill inputs from last row -1 in db then sent to the printer and then last row -2 then print it etc.. I have managed to return the json data from last n insered rows from database depending on the printmultiple value

The html

```
<div id="printableArea">
<div align="center">

<input type="text" name="barcode2"  id="barcode2" required readonly >
<input type="text" name="barcodecountry" id="barcodecountry"  >
<input type="text" name="barcodecountry" id="barcodecountry2"  >

<br>
 <div id="print">
</div>

<label id="idbar">id.:</label><input type="text" name="barcodesurname" id="barcodesurname"  required readonly>
<br>
<br>
<label id="pricebar">price:</label><input type="text" name="barcodename" id="barcodename"  required readonly>
<input type="text" name="barcodecountry" id="barcodecountry3">
</div> 
</div>

</div>
```

printablearea is the div that inputs are filled and i am sending for printing to printer

In my Js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('form').submit(function(event) {

        $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // remove the error class
        $('.help-block').remove(); // remove the error text





        var formData = {
            'surname'       : $('input[name=surname]').val(),
            'name'      : $('input[name=name]').val(),

            'telephone' : $("#telephone").val(),
            'mail' : $("#mail").val(),
            'barcode' : $("#barcode").val(),
            'customid' : $("#customid").val(),
            'ticketprice' : $("#ticketprice").val(),
            'seat' : $("#seat").val(),
            'printmultiple' :$("#printmultiple").val()

        };

        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', 
            url         : 'process2.php',
            data        : formData,
            dataType    : 'json', from the server
            encode      : true
        })

            .done(function(data) {



                console.log(data); 

                if ( ! data.success) {
                        if (data.errors.surname) {
                        $('#surname-group').addClass('has-error');
                        $('#surname-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.surname + '</div>');
                        }
                        else if (data.errors.name) {
                        $('#name-group').addClass('has-error'); 
                        $('#name-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.name + '</div>'); 
                        }



                } else {

 $.each(data.added, function (i,it){

    $('#printableArea').append(data.added[i]);
 });

  for(i=0; i<data.added[13]; i++){
                     $('#barcodecountry2').val(data.added[1]); 
                    $('#barcodesurname').val(data.added[0]);             
                    $('#barcodename').val(data.added[4]); 
                     $('#barcode2').val(data.added[2]);
                     $("#print").barcode(
    document.getElementById("barcode2").value,
    "code128" 
    );  
                $('#printableArea').print();
                 }

$('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');
    }
            })


            .fail(function(data) {


                console.log(data);
            });


        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

I want the returned data from json to fill the inputs for example the first 5 elements of json to be filled then print then next 5 then print . I have added code for printing depending on printmultiple value but only prints tha last row n times

below i add returned json data : `Object { 0: "7784", 1: "2016-10-18 23:16:01.000000", 2: "16221458721646", 3: "2016-10-19", 4: "8", 5: "normal", 6: null, 7: "admin", 8: "DASDSADAS", 9: "7884", 18 more… }`

Comment: it might help if you show sample contents of the `data` variable and its structure. Out of interest though, this is quite a strange way to print. Is this a report? Normally people aren't interested in printing forms with textboxes etc, they prefer the data to be formatted nicely and readable. A printed form won't generally look that nice. Forms are intended for inputting and capturing data, not displaying/printing it.

Comment: the form is for printing barcodes with data from db but if someone wants to print for example 5 barcodes i want the last 5 rows inserted on db because the barcodes takes barcode + 1 and is printed on the printer

Comment: the data that is returned from json 
 
Object { 0: "7784", 1: "2016-10-18 23:16:01.000000", 2: "16221458721646", 3: "2016-10-19", 4: "8", 5: "normal", 6: null, 7: "admin", 8: "DASDSADAS", 9: "7884", 18 more… }

Comment: I can what the form is for, I was asking why you are using form elements as the medium, not some other html which would be easier to format nicely? form elements are for input, not output. Please edit the question and include the JSON sample, formatted properly - it's very difficult to read code/data which is inserted into comments :-)

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution

```
   for(i=0; i<data.added[0].printmultiple; i++){
                     $('#barcodecountry2').val(data.added[i].signintime); 
                    $('#barcodesurname').val(data.added[i].customid);             //get id 
                    $('#barcodename').val(data.added[i].ticketprice); 
                     $('#barcode2').val(data.added[i].barcode);
                     $("#print").barcode( //div id print
    document.getElementById("barcode2").value,// Value barcode (dependent on the type of barcode)
    "code128" // type (string)
    );
```